# Java: Problems with TreeSet

Tags: java, generics, treeset

I have a class Odp. I want to use TreeSet to keep a sorted collection of Odp objects. However, I've been having problems.

```
public class OdpStorage {

    private TreeSet<Odp> collection = new TreeSet<Odp>(); 

    public addOdp(Odp o) {
          return collection.add(o);
    }

    public int size() {
          return collection.size();
    }

}
```

collection.add(Odp o) is supposed to do nothing if it's already in the tree, right? Somehow, this unit test fails:

```
OdpStorage ts = new OdpStorage();       
Odp ftw = new Odp("LOL");
    Odp ktr = new Odp("OMG");

    ts.addOdp(ftw);

    ts.addOdp(ftw); //should do nothing
    ts.addOdp(ftw); //should do nothing
    ts.addOdp(ftw); //should do nothing
    ts.addOdp(ktr);

assertEquals(2, ts.size());
```

The assertion fails. It expects 2, but the return value is 5. Why? Could the odp.equals() function be messed up?

Similarly, calling `collection.contains(o)` fails, even when the there is an object in the set `X` for which `o.equals(X)` returns true.

The .equals() function of Odp: (generated by Eclipse)

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Odp))
        return false;
    Gene other = (Odp) obj;
    if (sequence == null) {
        if (other.sequence != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!sequence.equals(other.sequence))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

compareTo:

```
/**
 * this = g0
 * if they are equal, g1 is presumed to come first
 * 
 *  @return -1 if g0 comes before g1; 1 if g0 comes after g1
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(Odp g1) {

    if (sequence.length() < g1.getSeq().length()) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (sequence.length() > g1.getSeq().length()) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (sequence.compareTo(g1.getSeq()) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

`hashCode()` is not overridden. Problem?

**UPDATE**
`hashCode()` is as follows:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((sequence == null) ? 0 : sequence.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

But that still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does Odp override hash and equals? If so, please post those.

Comment: it does not override hash, but it does override Equals. Posted above.

Comment: hashCode() is not used by TreeSet. A TreeSet uses a Comparator to compare and sort objects as they are added. HashMaps use hashcode, hence the hash in the name. TreeSet which is a sorted Set cannot and does not use hashes because they cannot be compared for purposes of ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `collection.add(o)` is failing to find the object in the backing `TreeMap`.  Does your `Odp` implement `Comparable` or are you setting a default `Comparable` on your `TreeSet` whose `compare` method you have implemented?  If so, you will need to ensure that your `compareTo` (for the `Comparable`), or your `Comparator` `compare` method will return `0` if the objects passed in are `equals`.

EDIT (in response to your comment to the original post):

[It is recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java/27609#27609) that you override `HashCode()` whenever you override `equals()`

EDIT2 in response to your `compareTo` implementation:

If `g0` and `g1` are equal, you should return 0.  This is the root of the problem.

Comment: Odp does indeed implement Comparable.

Comment: I would target the `compareTo` method in your debugging first.  Post it if you would like a review.

Comment: When I was using a TreeMap instead of TreeSet, it was sorting just fine. This leads me to believe that it's not an issue with implementing the Comparable interface.

Comment: +1. TreeSet and TreeMap both use compareTo() (or supplied Comparator) instead of equals()

Answer (score 3):

Your `compareTo` implementation never returns 0.  It should return 0 when the object instances are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Mate cleanup your equals, its got too many if/elses. replace it with a nice do/while with lots of condition tests. If all the tests pass then reutrn true...Yes its got "goto" statements but its very easy to read and even easier to insert new conditions as necessary without lots of nesting. Nesting if/elses is evil. Using "elses" is evil and almost always never needed.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object object) {
    boolean equals = false;

    do {
        if (this == object) {
            equals = true;
            break;
        }
        if (false == super.equals(object)) {
            break;
        }
        final DocumentView view = Unsafe.cast(object);
        if (false == this.document.equals(view.document)) {
            break;
        }
        if (this.revision != view.revision) {
            break;
        }
        if (false == this.user.equals(view.user)) {
            break;
        }
        if (false == this.timestamp.equals(view.timestamp)) {
            break;
        }
        equals = true;
    } while (false);

    return equals;
}
```

Comment: if (!...) {
    return false;
}

return true;
is much prettier and without the do while.

Comment: It's better to haveone return, it's easier to set a single breakpoint or guard rather than having to set many.

Comment: If you ever have to come back it's quicker to set a single breakpoint than the time to type the wrapping do while. In short don't be lazy and smart using returns rather than type a bit more and have a single return.